# firebase.database is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to upgrade from earlier firebase version to the latest in my [ionic project](http://ionicframework.com/). I followed [this](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web) tutorial for upgrade. In step 4 from this page I am stuck on the last statement `firebase.database().ref();`.

Error message

```
TypeError: firebase.database is not a function
```

Below is my code. Kindly help.

```
...

// Initialize Firebase
this.config = {
    apiKey: "some-api-key",
    authDomain: "myapp.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://myapp.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "project-somenumber.appspot.com",
};

...

this.authWithOAuthPopup = function(type) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    console.log(service.config);    // ---> Object {apiKey: "some-api-key", authDomain: "myapp.firebaseapp.com", databaseURL: "https://myapp.firebaseio.com", storageBucket: "project-somenumber.appspot.com"}
    firebase.initializeApp(service.config);
    console.log(firebase);  // ---> Object {SDK_VERSION: "3.0.5", INTERNAL: Object}
    service.rootRef = firebase.database().ref(); //new Firebase("https://rsb2.firebaseio.com"); ---> I am getting error on this line "TypeError: firebase.database is not a function"
    service.rootRef.authWithOAuthPopup(type, function(error, authData) {
        if (error) {
            service.authError = error;
            switch (error.code) {
                case "INVALID_EMAIL":
                    console.log("The specified user account email is invalid.");
                    break;
                case "INVALID_PASSWORD":
                    console.log("The specified user account password is incorrect.");
                    break;
                case "INVALID_USER":
                    console.log("The specified user account does not exist.");
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log("Error logging user in:", error);
            }
            deferred.resolve(service.authError);
        } else {
            service.authData = authData;
            console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
            deferred.resolve(service.authData);
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

var service = this;
```

**Update**

After adding latest database library this questions problem is solved.

Updating my code here

```
this.authWithOAuthPopup = function(type) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    console.log(service.config);
    firebase.initializeApp(service.config);
    console.log(firebase);
    service.rootRef = firebase.database(); //.ref(); //new Firebase("https://rsb2.firebaseio.com");

    var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
    firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
        if (result.credential) {
            // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
            var token = result.credential.accessToken;
            console.log(result);
            // ...
        }
        // The signed-in user info.
        var user = result.user;
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        // The email of the user's account used.
        var email = error.email;
        // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
        var credential = error.credential;
        // ...
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 140, accepted):

I ran into this with Ionic and it turned out that I wasn't including everything when using the latest Firebase Client. If you've included Firebase as `firebase-app`, then the Database and Auth pieces need to be required separately since they aren't bundled when including Firebase in this way.

Add the following to your `index.html` after you include `firebase-app.js`

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

Obviously you don't need to use the CDN, you could use [bower](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-bower) (probably the preferred way with Ionic) or [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) with Browserify.

```
// Browserify Setup
var firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/auth');
require('firebase/database');
```

Snippet below taken from the [Firebase Web Setup Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)

> You can reduce the amount of code your app uses by just including the features you need. The individually installable components are:

> firebase-app - The core firebase client (required).
> firebase-auth - Firebase Authentication (optional).
> firebase-database - The Firebase Realtime Database (optional).
> firebase-storage - Firebase Storage (optional).

> From the CDN, include the individual components you need (include firebase-app first)

Comment: It is crazy, because the official docs for firebase (https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) do not currently show the link to https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.0/firebase-database.js  They just say, use the appropriate libraries.  If you look under the CDN section firebase-database.js is not listed but this is the one you need for the realtime db.

Answer (score 5):

A bit late to the party, but in case some one wanted to know the syntax in angular, (or Ionic 4) just add this to your .module.ts file (Note, as peterb mentioned, the /database import)

```
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

i solved this issue by giving the url in the constructor
firebase.database('https://123.firebaseio.com')

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are using

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase.js"></script>
```

Firebase `authWithOAuthPopup` has changed a little bit in the new version.

Now you don't use the ref to call authentication methods. You should be using `firebase.auth()` insted.

```
var auth = firebase.auth();
var provider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
  // User signed in!
  var uid = result.user.uid;
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error occurred
});
```

Comment: The [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login) recommends to use redirect method for mobile. So I am able to authenticate using the facebook using redirect method, but this reloads my webpage (currently testing ionic app on chrome) and I am not able to get the payload details. I have updated my the code above

Answer (score 0):

[Firebase database docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start?hl=pt-br)

I know that many will appear here because of the new modular version of the Firebase SDK. Currently, to instantiate the database you need to **import getDatabase**:

**New Approach (SDK 9):**

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const firebaseDb = getDatabase(app);
```

SDK 8- (olders)

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/database';


const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const firebaseDb = app.database();
```

Answer (score -1):

Also faced this problem on @angular/firebase 5.1.2, solved when updated @angular/cli and all dependencies to the latest version.

Answer (score -1):

For people facing similar error(this._database.native.on is not a function) in React-native -

1. run the pod install - after adding firebase new service(database/auth ...)
2. terminate the metro bundler and restart it using "npx react-native start"
3. run "npx react-native run-ios"

This will create a new build and the error should be gone.

Ref: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/3379

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
var firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/database');
```

Answer (score -1):

`npm install --save firebase`

Then:

`require("firebase/database");`

You need to add all of the firebase products you are using by way of `require()` as shown above.

Answer (score -2):

I have the same error ***-firebase.database is not a function-*** but with **different situation** you just need to add

above  and  the link of javascript that contain the Firebase configuration.

You may also try to use the **defer** Attribute in your script as it will not load the scripts until page elements are loaded.