# How to get Firebase reference when using Polymerfire?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polymer-1.0, polymerfire

I am new to Polymer and I am stuck on setting the database data. I manged to make email authentication work and I need to save user data after user creation. I initialize the app with firebase-app element.

Here is the important part:

```
this.$.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).then(function (user) {
                    user.sendEmailVerification();
                    document.getElementById("emaildialog").toggle();
                    var view = document.getElementById("r_view");

                    firebase.database().ref('/user/' + user['uid']).set({
                        name: view.name,
                        surname: view.surName
                    }).catch(function (err) {
                        console.log(err.message);
                    });
                })
```

User is successfully created but the user data won't get saved and

> firebase.database is not a function"

error is thrown. I guess it's because I don't have access to `firebase.database` function in the scope. I found [many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38250513/3952906) how to solve the issue using pure JavaScript, but I'm not sure what is the official "Polymer way".

EDIT:
I still can't get it to work. i managed to get a reference of app object but it seems like there is no database method available. I wrote a simple function for debugging:

```
    debugFunction: function () {
        if (!!this.user) {
            var fb = this.$.auth.app;
            console.log(!!fb); // Output is true,
            var database = fb.database(); 
        }
    }
```

I get the "Uncaught TypeError: fb.database is not a function(…)" once more.

Thanks in advance, Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the reference of the firebase app inside your firebase-auth element. Make sure you do this outside of the callback function so you won't have to deal with getting the proper scope of `this`. If you must, you can do `.bind` or arrow functions.

```
var app = this.$.auth.app;
```

Then after that you can do `app.database()` as a replacement for the firebase one.