# react-boilerplate not working with firebase

Tags: firebase, webpack, server-side-rendering, next.js, react-boilerplate

I have imported firebase like this,

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const config = {

};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

export const database = firebase.database().ref('/posts');
```

Then I got this error:

```
__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_firebase_app__.database is not a function
```

so I tried this way.

```
const firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/auth');
require('firebase/database');
```

Then I got this error.

```
firebase.initializeApp is not a function
```

Does anyone know how to work with server side rendered react with webpack, firebase ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [firebase.database is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38248723/firebase-database-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
export const database = firebase.database().ref('/posts')
```

try :

```
const database = firebase.database().ref('/posts')
module.exports = database
```

Comment: thanks, but then I got __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13__containers_App_firebase__.database.on