# Keep getting an Uncaught TypeError using new version of Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

I've used firebase in the past for a few projects and config has been super easy. I'm experiencing issues with the new version of firebase - and keep getting a TypeError 
 saying `firebase.database() is not a function`

Here are the script tags at the bottom of the body section in my HTML:

```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="assets/app.js"></script>
```

and my JS config looks like this:

```
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: apiKey,
  authDomain: authDomain,
  databaseURL: dbURL,
  projectId: id,
  storageBucket: sb,
  messagingSenderId: msid,
  appId: appId
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

var database = firebase.database()
```

The issue is not in the config because firebase.initializeApp works fine - but  I cant seem to find any updates to the official docs that would explains why firebase.database() doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: @yoga sure it does, it explicitly says so in the docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start - i've also used it before. Seems as if something isn't working in the newer version

Comment: sorry . my bad. this is JS

Comment: try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38250513/11460314

Comment: @yoga figured it out, posted the answer below if you're interested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay was able to figure this out on my own...

I only imported the basic firebase script:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

BUT I also needed to import the developmental firebase SDK to give me access to the realtime database functionality, hence why `firebase.database()` wasn't working. So I had to import a new script after the one referenced above:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
```

Database functions seems to be working fine now.