# Uncaught TypeError: firebase.database is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in firebase.I make a simple login form with Javascript. and iI want to store this data in firebase realtime database . but I am getting this error.

Uncaught TypeError: firebase.database is not a function

There is all my code that is inside the body tag.But still getting this error in my console

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Contact Form</h2>
            <div class="alert alert-success success-message" style="display:none;">Form submitted successfully.</div>
            <form id="contactForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFullName">Full Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control fullname" id="exampleFullName" placeholder="Enter Full Name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleEmail">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control email" id="exampleEmail" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleSubject">Subject</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control subject" id="exampleSubject" placeholder="Enter Subject" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleMessage">Message</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control message" id="exampleMessage" placeholder="Enter Message" cols="30" rows="10" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
 var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();

  // Reference messages collection
var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('contactformmessages');

$('#contactForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var newMessageRef = messagesRef.push();
    newMessageRef.set({
        name: $('.fullname').val(),
        email: $('.email').val(),
        subject: $('.subject').val(),
        message: $('.message').val()
    });

    $('.success-message').show();

    $('#contactForm')[0].reset();
}); 

    </script>
</body>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: How did you add Firebase to your project?  Please edit the question to explain what you did and show your script includes.

Comment: Show the HTML file if any as well. need to see where have you added the Firebase script. Faced similar issues yesterday.

Comment: I showed only those where I am getting error.These are in script tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [firebase.database is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38248723/firebase-database-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @AwaisHassan follow CherryDT answer and put those script tags inside BODY tags

Comment: I placed it but still getting error

Comment: Show all the scripts you have.. post it here

Comment: You can check now

Comment: Put all those at top of body tag and where is `<script src="app.js"></script>` ?? Link to your JS file

Comment: How have you linked HTML and JS?? Add above line, and write your JS file name there

Comment: No. My all HTML and JS code  in one file .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try including this:

```
<script src = "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

After linking the firebase script.

Comment: Bro this work but after fill the form when I submit then this error is happen.Repo.ts:633 Uncaught (in promise) Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied

Comment: You have to change your realtime database rules.

Comment: How ? I am new in firebase

Comment: Go to your firebase console, select database,then realtime database. Goto rules tab and set ```{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}```

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a quick fix, You need to set better security rules as you make your app better. You should never let your client access the database directly. @Dharmaraj might have a better fix for this.

Comment: How to make better security?

Comment: Use firebase cloud functions.. Let only authenticated users modify the db.