# React Redux Firebase/Firestore - Error: Real Time Database or Firestore must be included to enable user profile

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting this error below in my react redux firebase web app console?

Error: Real Time Database or Firestore must be included to enable user profile
    at watchUserProfile 
    at handleAuthStateChange 
    at Object.next

and in the console state.firebase.profile does not show any data from the firestore database?

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same issue and finally found the problem!

In the file where you initialize the firebase app you also need to import the firebase database with the following:

```
import 'firebase/database';
```

Here is a link to where I found the solution: [firebase.database is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38248723/firebase-database-is-not-a-function)