# TypeError: firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.database is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to add Firebase to my ReactJS app and having some trouble doing so. I'm following the guide from https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#node.js-apps to understand how it works.
Attached is a screenshot of the error.

My Firebase specific code sits in another file called `firebase.js` and I call it from my `index.js` file (this is just a first pass, I want to see if I can get connectivity to the Realtime Database).

`firebase.js`

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "....",
    authDomain: "....",
    databaseURL: ".....",
    projectId: "....",
    storageBucket: "....",
    messagingSenderId: "....",
    appId: "....",
    measurementId: "...."
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

firebase.database().ref().set({
    'name': 'blah'
});
```

I then go on to import this file in `index.js` to see if it works. Here's the error I see:
[image]

I have temporarily changed the rules on the DB to allow anyone to write to it (authentication hasn't been added yet).

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Credit to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38250513/6205548.

Turns out every component now needs to be imported individually. Adding the line `import 'firebase/database'` solved the issue.