# Implementing firebase.database().ref returns error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use firebase.database.ref() as mentioned [in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Reference).

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.firestore().settings( { timestampsInSnapshots: true })
// firebase.analytics();

const storage = firebase.storage();
const store = firebase.firestore();
const authenticate = firebase.auth();
    
var matchref = firebase.database().ref("users");
```

and it's returning this error

> firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.default.database is not a
> function

I'm using version 8 so this shouldn't be happening.

Comment: I expect that you forgot to import the Realtime Database SDK. Make sure you include it as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38248723/firebase-database-is-not-a-function
If that doesn't address the problem, edit your question to show how you **import/include** the SDKs.

Comment: This is in the same file where I'm initializing the firebase app so I don't know if I have to do that

Comment: It's magically working now